# Evaluating $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}nf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function with $f(0)=0$. I have to evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}nf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Since the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$
and $f$ is continuous due to its differentiability, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)=0$$
so, the limit would be:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}nf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\infty\cdot0$$
so may I conclude this limit doesn't exist?

Comment: That is incorrect, you can't conclude anything from $\infty\cdot 0$. The limit does exist and equals something nice.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I see. What is incorrect?

Comment: Note that the function is differentiable at $x=0$. What is derivative of f at $0$?

Comment: Hint: Are you familiar with L'hospital's rule?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: L'Hospital's not required at all.

Comment: @Koro why could I conclude $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: @Koro -- so? It solves the problem, and is machinery that lots of people are familiar with.

Comment: Because $f'$ exists at $x=0$ so what do you get using sequential criteria?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes, I'm familiar with it.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: It does. I just thought it's overkill to use L'Hospital. :)

Comment: @Koro I still didn't get why could I conclude that.

Comment: I was answering the question at the end of your post. You cannot conclude the limit does not exist. To answer the question in the cleanest way possible, use the definition of the derivative at a point.

Comment: You should check your product rule for limits again: the rewrite $\lim a b = \lim a \cdot \lim b$ requires that the limits on the right both exist.  To convince yourself that this is required, consider $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle f'( 0)$ exists, it follows that the limit
\begin{equation*}
\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f( x) -f( 0)}{x-0} =\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f( x)}{x} =f'( 0)
\end{equation*}
Hence the limit
\begin{equation*}
\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f( x)}{x} =f'( 0)
\end{equation*}
That is for every sequence $\displaystyle x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ (such that $\displaystyle x_{n} \neq 0$ for any $\displaystyle n$), $\displaystyle \frac{f( x_{n})}{x_{n}}\rightarrow f'( 0)$

In particular, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0\Longrightarrow $$\displaystyle \frac{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow f'( 0)$.

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{1}{n}$ is a sequence converging to 0. $f$ is differentiable at 0. Therefore, for any sequence $x_n$ converging to 0, $\frac{f(x_n) - f(0)}{x_n}$, must converge to $f^{\prime}(0)$. Hence the limit exists and its value is $f^{\prime}(0)$.

Comment: I thought that would be understood in these kinds of contexts - where we leave out the $x_n$ which are zero.